# Kite vs Jedi, ranked and good for new to python

Tags: python

I have been working on learning python for a few months and had two questions. Is there much of a difference between options like Kite or Jedi and if you are new to programming is it a good idea to use either of them while learning? The only comparisons I saw did not appear unbiased. Any thoughts are appreciated thanks.

https://www.kite.com/integrations/kite-vs-jedi/

The programs do actually both exist for Python contrary to the first comment

Answer (score 13):

Disclaimer: I am the author of Jedi.

In general I would probably doubt that Kite is smarter in understanding Python. I'm pretty sure Jedi is still smarter about that, given that there are almost no open issues in Jedi's issue tracker.

However, if you like stuff like "line-of-code completions" or relevance ranking of autocompletion terms this might be what you want. Jedi does not do such things, because Jedi is good at exactly one thing: Understanding Python code. Kite tries to do a lot more. They do some type inference as well, but add their "machine learning" that might help some times and probably also produces false positives at times.

There have been [issues](https://qz.com/1043614/this-startup-learned-the-hard-way-that-you-do-not-piss-off-open-source-programmers/) in the past with kite and its privacy model. I am not sure if it's better now, but just be aware that there's a chance that kite will upload your code to some cloud service. Maybe not now, but this might as well change in the future.

Comment: In the one hand there is company who involved in shady [behavior](https://theoutline.com/post/1953/how-a-vc-funded-company-is-undermining-the-open-source-community) behavior in the past, who wants to deploy compiled close source code to you computer with a mandatory registration. In the one hand, there is software that is free and open. Kite makes stuff easier sure, but when Jedi tell me something, I don't need to double check. Jedi is much more reliable.

Answer (score -3):

The two have nothing to do with other, therefore it makes no sense to compare them. That's like asking for a comparison between a Toyota Prius and the number π.

JEDI (Joint Endeavour of Delphi Innovators) is an umbrella organization for a number of projects related to the Delphi Programming Language. It is somewhat comparable to the role the Apache Foundation used to play for the Java ecosystem.

Kite is an Emacs frontend for the WebKit Inspector, i.e. it is a tool for debugging ECMAScript, HTML, CSS, and websites in Emacs. The project has been dead for many years, the last commit was in 2013.

Neither of the two are even remotely related to either each or to Python.

Comment: Kite - AI Coding Assistant for Python and JavaScriptwww.kite.com
Code faster with Kite's AI-powered autocomplete plugin for Python and JavaScript developers, featuring Multi-Line Completions. Works 100% locally. I have used Kite before for python so I dont understand that comment

Comment: Kite vs. Jedi - Which is the Best Autocomplete for Python?www.kite.com › integrations › kite-vs-jedi
Kite vs. Jedi · Kite delivers better completions, more often · Kite plugs into your favorite code editors · Benefit from deep learning while you code · Kite is free to use. From Kite's website. Help me understand how neither are related to Python

Comment: Kite's own website compares the options so are they wrong in that they are related or am I missing something else here

Comment: Jörg: The question itself is fine, the tags are just wrong. Jedi is also an autocompletion engine for Python and Kite is something similar. IMO you can probably correct the tags and delete this answer.